# UsersController inside of namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying have a different frontend and backend view for certain parts of my app, starting with Users.

I'm getting the error `uninitialized constant Office::DashboardController`, which I understand means it can't find the controller? I feel like it's an issue with how I've setup the namespace / directories, but I can't seem to work it.

*routes.rb*

```
namespace :office do
   root to: "dashboard#index"
   resources :users
end
```

*office/dashboards_controller.rb*

```
class Office::DashboardsController < ApplicationController
    layout "office"
end
```

*office/users_controller.rb*

```
class UsersController < Office::DashboardController
    def index
      @users = User.all
    end

    def show
      @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
    end
end
```

There is a chance I've completely messed this up and it's totally wrong...if that's the case, I would love some feedback!

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try `DashboardsController` (plural)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `DashboardController` inside `Office` module, but `UsersController` isn't in the module. Why is that? Both of them are in the same folder.

So, either

```
class Office::UsersController < Office::DashboardController
```

or

```
module Office
  class UsersController < DashboardController
```

should work as expected.

Tip: you can run `rails routes` and see folders/class names Rails expects.

Comment: The later is [actually preferable](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#classes--modules) due to how module nesting works in Ruby.